Use Laravel Livewire 3 without php artisan serve
I've followed the tutorial in the Livewire 3, but it only works after starting the server with php artisan serve. I'd live to run it like a regular site with MAMP, because I have a shared hosting and I don't have access to the terminal. When I try without artisan serve it can't locate the file http://localhost:8888/livewire/update.

Could it be that you hardcoded that route or URL?

No, I didn’t, my localhost route for this example is: http://localhost:8888/laravel_counter/public/

Do not use subfolders, you need to define a virtualhost that points to the public folder. Try searching for "mamp virtualhost"

Laravel must be run with the root path.
Run it with http://***/.
Remove laravel_counter/public.
The reason why it is said many times not to use XAMPP or MAMP is because they do not have the necessary settings for Laravel.
You need to learn about web servers before using Laravel.

in AppServiceProvider boot function, add this code:
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('/your_directory/public/livewire/update', $handle);
});

Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
    return config('app.debug') 
        ? Route::get('/your_directory/public/livewire/livewire.js', $handle)
        : Route::get('/your_directory/public/livewire/livewire.min.js', $handle);
});

replace your_directory with the name of your folder
